# Where can I find KIS 2010 offline DataBases?

Tags: anti-virus, updates, kaspersky

I have Dial up (slow) connection , and KIS(Kaspersky internet security) 2010 (For Windows 7) , I need offline databases to update KIS 2010 , Where Can I find that , a new databases ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they stopped manual updates on version 7.0, I have no idea if this is compatible with version 2010 or not. [Here is the link](http://www.kaspersky.co.uk/avupdates).

They also have a [product update section](http://www.kaspersky.co.uk/productupdates) - but I think this is for the actual program and not just the virus database updates.

Comment: thanx for advice ,
yes they stop it after v7 , but some websites offer this update for free to any one , I need a good one that give it day by day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this tool: http://support.kaspersky.com/updater?level=2 or follow this method: http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2010/update?qid=208280096

Comment: I used it , but it takes so long time , after all that it didn't give you any thing , and you can't know if  you will stay a moment or an ancient

Comment: It's not clear: do you look for a faster mirror server or a way to download the updates from another computer/connection?

Comment: Yes I mean that

Comment: Which that? :))  If it's the faster mirror, and your ISP and location to the question...

Comment: No I mean "to download the updates from another computer/connection"